# Using jolt operation to filter the json fields

Tags: json, jolt

Given the following input:

```json
[
  {
    "users": [
      {
        "external_id": "aaa",
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "doe",
        "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "external_id": "bbb"
      },
      {
        "external_id": "ccc"
      }
    ],
    "message": "success"
  }
]
```

I need the following output:

```json
[
  {
    "external_id": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "external_id": "ccc"
  }
]
```

I want to filter external_id that doesn't have first_name,last_name and email associated with it
I just tried shift operation and it gets all the external_id.

Comment: Hi Vedha. You can also check the existence by using `~` operator. Check the related answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "users": {
          "*": "=concat('',@(0))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "users": {
          "*": {
            "{*=*}": {
              "@": "data[].&(1,1).&(1,2)"
            },
            "{*=*,*": {
              "@1": "r"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "[].&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use **`~`** operator to check the existence of one of the attributes from `first_name`,`last_name` or `email`, in this case I've chosen `first_name` for the **modify** transformation spec. Then dive up to the innermost object to derive the matching values while making others ***null*** to be prepared to be extinguished within the next transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "users": {
          "*": {
            "~first_name": {
              "external_id": "=(@(2,external_id))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "users": {
          "*": {
            "first_name": {// pick up the innermost attributes named first_name 
              "external_id": "[#3].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// get rid of null components
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```